# Reactjs calculate how many pixels in one vw and vh

Tags: css, reactjs

Im trying to find a way to find the amount of pixels in one VH in reactjs with in-line styling. For example something like

```
this.num_pixels = calculate(num_vh=50)
```

Outputs 540 in a 1080 by 1800 computer.

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to scale an image to take up 40vw and 40vh, and then when someone clicks on it I want to find the vh and vw value of the click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `1vh` = 1% of screen height.

So, it could be something like:

```js
const convertVhToPx = (vh=50) => {
    const oneVhInPx = window.innerHeight / 100;
    return oneVhInPx * vh;
};
```

It might **not** be super-duper precise because [there are quite a few quirks with vh units in general](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/) but you might easily adjust this snippet a tiny bit to make it work for your particular use case.